# El valor del Input no actualiza correctamente

Tags: php

en el siguiente script actualizo dinámicamente valores en select e input según el valor seleccionado, pero en el caso de el input "nro_venta_input"., este no se actualiza correctamente y algunas veces toma el valor de un elemento que aún no se ha seleccionado (#docrelacionado) específicamente cuando selecciono "serie", se cargan valores a "docrelacionado" y cuando selecciono un "option" de este elemento recién debería actualizar el valor del input, sin embargo al seleccionar "serie" se muestra un valor en el input sin haber seleccionado "docrelacionado". Espero se entienda la consulta y me puedan apoyar para dar con la solución.
El código:

```js
  let tipodocSelect = document.getElementById("tipocomprobante");
  let serieSelect = document.getElementById("serie");
  let docRelacionadoSelect = $('#docrelacionado');
  let nroVentaInput = $('#nro_venta_input');

  let opcionesPorTipo = {
    "07": ["Seleccionar", "FC01", "BC01"],
    "08": ["Seleccionar", "FD01", "BD01"]
  };

  function actualizarSerieOptions() {
    let tipoSeleccionado = tipodocSelect.value;
    let opciones = opcionesPorTipo[tipoSeleccionado] || [];
    serieSelect.innerHTML = "";

    opciones.forEach(function (opcion) {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = opcion;
      option.text = opcion;
      serieSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
    obtenerCorrelativo();
  }
  tipodocSelect.addEventListener("change", actualizarSerieOptions);

  // Función para manejar el cambio en el selector "serie"
  function handleSerieChange() {
    obtenerCorrelativo();
    obtenerComprobantes();
    obtenerNroVentaIdCliente();
  }

  // Agregar un evento de cambio al select "serie"
  $('#serie').change(handleSerieChange);
  function obtenerCorrelativo() {
    let selectedSerie = serieSelect.value;
    let correlativoInput = $('#correlativo');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'obtener_ncorrelativo.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { serie: selectedSerie },
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.error) {
          alert('Error: ' + data.error);
        } else {
          var nuevoCorrelativo = isNaN(parseInt(data.num_doc) + 1) ? "1" : (parseInt(data.num_doc) + 1);
          correlativoInput.val(nuevoCorrelativo);
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  }
  function obtenerComprobantes() {
    let selectedSerie = serieSelect.value;
    console.log("selectedSerie", selectedSerie);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'obtener_comprobante.php',
      data: { serie: selectedSerie },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
        docRelacionadoSelect.empty();
        if (response && 'serie-num_doc' in response) {
          let nro_venta = response['serie-num_doc'][0].nro_venta;
          nroVentaInput.val(nro_venta);
          docRelacionadoSelect.append($('<option>', {
            value: 'Seleccionar',
            text: 'Seleccionar'
          }));
          $.each(response['serie-num_doc'], function (index, item) {
            docRelacionadoSelect.append($('<option>', {
              value: item['serie-num_doc'],
              text: item['serie-num_doc']
            }));
          });
        } else {
          docRelacionadoSelect.append($('<option>', {
            value: '',
            text: 'No se encontraron registros'
          }));
        }
      },
      error: function () {
        docRelacionadoSelect.empty();
        docRelacionadoSelect.append($('<option>', {
          value: '',
          text: 'Error en la solicitud AJAX'
        }));
      }
    });
  }
  function obtenerNroVentaIdCliente() {
    let serieNumDoc = docRelacionadoSelect.val();
    console.log("serieNumDoc", serieNumDoc);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'obtener_datos_venta.php',
      data: { serie_num_doc: serieNumDoc },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
        if (response && 'nro_venta' in response && 'id_cliente' in response) {
          let nro_venta = response['nro_venta'];
          nroVentaInput.val(nro_venta);
          console.log("nro_venta", nro_venta);
          //$('#id_cliente').text(response.id_cliente);
        } else {
          nroVentaInput.val('No encontrado');
          //$('#id_cliente').text('No encontrado');
        }
      },
      error: function () {
        nroVentaInput.val('Error en la solicitud AJAX');
        //$('#id_cliente').text('Error en la solicitud AJAX');
      }
    });
  }
  tipodocSelect.addEventListener("change", actualizarSerieOptions);
 
  $('#docrelacionado').change(function () {
    //alert("cambio en docrel");
    obtenerNroVentaIdCliente();
  });
  actualizarSerieOptions();
```

---

Boque HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <label>TipoComprobante:</label>
      <br>
      <select class="custom-select" style="width:150px;" name="tipocomprobante" id="tipocomprobante">
        <option value="07" selected>Nota de Crédito</option>
        <option value="08">Nota de Débito</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <label>Serie:</label>
      <br>
      <select class="custom-select" style="width:120px;" name="serie" id="serie">
        <!-- Opción en blanco para requerir selección -->
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="nro_venta_input" name="nro_venta_input">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </form>
      <input type="text" id="correlativo" name="correlativo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <label>Fecha de
                      Emisión:</label>
      <br>
      <input style="width: 120px;" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <label>Docum. Relacionado:</label>
      <br>
      <select class="custom-select" style="width:150px;" id="docrelacionado" name="docrelacionado">
        <!-- Opción en blanco para requerir selección -->
        <option value="Seleccionar"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola. Sin un ejemplo del HTML con el que trabaja este código es imposible que podamos ver el problema.

Comment: El código debe ir en la parte de la pregunta, no en la parte de respuestas. A ver si entendí, es un código largo y no eres muy claro explicando el caso. ¿El problema es que el elemento cuya referencia en el código es `nroVentaInput` se actualiza cuando no debe? ¿Cuál es la lógica para actualizar ese elemento? No la explicas con claridad en la pregunta y ese elemento se modifica varias veces a lo largo del código. Este es un problema de depuración, si te sientas a analizar la lógica, poniendo puntos de interrupción o `alert` por las partes donde se va modificando el elemento, verás el problema.